# How to load the current Kubernetes cluster configuration with KOPS?

Tags: configuration, kubernetes, kops, google-kubernetes-engine

Using KOPS to retrieve the configuration be used with the following:

`kops get cluster --name <cluster-name> --output yaml`

Then, we have to call the instance groups configuration with the following:

`kops get ig --name <cluster-name> --output yaml`

Joining the documents require to add the yaml separator `---`.

Is there a simpler way to retrieve the current Kubernetes Cluster configuration with KOPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1758#issuecomment-336604987, the following command will print out the original configuration used to create the cluster:

`kops get -o yaml`

The configuration will include the entire cluster definition!